# Identifying damaged WRT54GL pcb smd parts

Tags: wrt54gl

My WRT54GL pcb is damaged in an accident, a bookshelf fell on it.
Some smd parts broken off from the pcb. I marked the missing smd parts.
Unfortunately I could not find the damaged parts after the accident.
I would like to repair it definitely!
Do somebody have an idea what is the exact the of the missing IC? (UC) and the the capacitor?
I was able read the label under the marked IC (UC1), it says UH50A. (I'm not sure the H letter, maybe it's a W letter)

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://cse.buffalo.edu/~bina/cse321/fall2014/xinu/wrt54gl.pdf) help?

Comment: If that doesn't, then the next best thing is a schematic from the manufacturer!

Comment: Might be simpler to buy a new router.